# Cascade destroy() in associated table with paranoid:true NOT WORK

Tags: sequelize.js

Issue with this problem opened over 8(!) years! https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2586

Associated records didn't deleted while destroy parent record in paranoid:true.

I try to reproduce the test from https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/8d3e1dc94917ab6a0acc3ff8d4cb1b35bfdfa70c/test/integration/associations/has-many.test.js#L1132 but this test is failed.

```js
'use strict';

const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

(async () => {
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('x', 'x', 'x', {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        define: {
            charset: 'utf8mb4',
            freezeTableName: false,
            createdAt: 'created_at',
            updatedAt: 'updated_at',
            deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
            timestamps: true,
            underscored: true,
            paranoid: true,
        },
        //logging: (...msg) => console.log(msg),
    });

    const Task = sequelize.define('Task', { title: DataTypes.STRING });
    const User = sequelize.define('User', { username: DataTypes.STRING });

    User.hasMany(Task, { foreignKey: { onDelete: 'cascade' } });

    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });

    const [user, task] = await Promise.all([
        User.create({ username: 'foo' }),
        Task.create({ title: 'task' }),
    ]);

    await user.setTasks([task]);
    await user.destroy();
    const tasks = await Task.findAll();

    console.log('tasks:', tasks);
})();
```

Sequelize generate SQL to create Tasks table with `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)` but in code `onDelete: 'cascade'` - why?

This script run SQL UPDATE on table Tasks, but it not update `deleted_at` - why?

```
x % node cascade
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tasks`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
Executing (default): SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME as constraint_name,CONSTRAINT_NAME as constraintName,CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA as constraintSchema,CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA as constraintCatalog,TABLE_NAME as tableName,TABLE_SCHEMA as tableSchema,TABLE_SCHEMA as tableCatalog,COLUMN_NAME as columnName,REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA as referencedTableSchema,REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA as referencedTableCatalog,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME as referencedTableName,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME as referencedColumnName FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME = 'tasks' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME!='PRIMARY' AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='x' AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
Executing (default): SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME as constraint_name,CONSTRAINT_NAME as constraintName,CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA as constraintSchema,CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA as constraintCatalog,TABLE_NAME as tableName,TABLE_SCHEMA as tableSchema,TABLE_SCHEMA as tableCatalog,COLUMN_NAME as columnName,REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA as referencedTableSchema,REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA as referencedTableCatalog,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME as referencedTableName,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME as referencedColumnName FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME = 'users' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME!='PRIMARY' AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='x' AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tasks`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `username` VARCHAR(255), `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `deleted_at` DATETIME, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tasks`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(255), `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `deleted_at` DATETIME, `user_id` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `tasks`
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`username`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?);
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`,`title`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?);
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`, `user_id` AS `UserId` FROM `tasks` AS `Task` WHERE (`Task`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `Task`.`user_id` = 1);
Executing (default): UPDATE `tasks` SET `user_id`=?,`updated_at`=? WHERE (`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `id` IN (1))
Executing (default): UPDATE `users` SET `deleted_at`=?,`updated_at`=? WHERE `id` = ?
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`, `user_id` AS `UserId` FROM `tasks` AS `Task` WHERE (`Task`.`deleted_at` IS NULL);
tasks: [
  Task {
    dataValues: {
      id: 1,
      title: 'task',
      created_at: 2022-11-21T20:38:12.000Z,
      updated_at: 2022-11-21T20:38:12.000Z,
      deleted_at: null,
      UserId: 1
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 1,
      title: 'task',
      created_at: 2022-11-21T20:38:12.000Z,
      updated_at: 2022-11-21T20:38:12.000Z,
      deleted_at: null,
      UserId: 1
    },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

- Sequelize version: sequelize@6.25.4, @sequelize/core@7.0.0-alpha.10
- Node.js version: v16.15.1
- If TypeScript related: TypeScript version: N/A
- Database & Version: MySQL v16.15.1
- Connector library & Version: mysql2@2.3.3

Comment: Did you find out what `cascade` option means? `Only used in conjuction with TRUNCATE. Truncates all tables that have foreign-key references to the named table, or to any tables added to the group due to CASCADE.`

Comment: I mean that cascade can use with destroy() w/o truncate:true. I cannot find out that it can use only with truncate. Please give me a link. Also, now I try to reproduce for example test from sequelize repo https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/8d3e1dc94917ab6a0acc3ff8d4cb1b35bfdfa70c/test/integration/associations/has-many.test.js#L1132

Comment: See https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-destroy

Comment: @Anatoly cascade not only used in truncate.

Comment: The documentation says `cascade` and `truncate` work together and moreover `cascade` doesn't make sense without indicating `truncate`.

Comment: I don't want dispute. This issue confirmed by sequelize mainteners and the problem of not working cascade on destroy() only if paranoid:true. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2586

Comment: It's quite simple:: `onDelete: 'cascade'` was originally added to support the ability to delete cascadely by using the built-in DB ability to do it and nothing more. It has nothing in common with with soft-deletion because DB knows nothing about it. So the only way to do it is to use hooks or explicit `destroy` calls on associated records.

Comment: @Anatoly, certainly, captain!